# Laravel with Arabic Slugs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i'm using Laravel 6 to build a blog application
and the language of this app is Arabic
but there is a problem with slug ,it looks like that Laravel doesn't support Arabic.

any idea to fix this?

Controller

```
public function post($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    return view('content.post',compact('post'));
}
```

Store Method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title'         => 'required|max:255',
        'slug'          => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:posts',
        'body'          => 'required',
    ));
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = Str::slug($request->slug, '-');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('admin/posts')->with('success', 'post is successfully saved');
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function

```
public function slug($string, $separator = '-') {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    $string = trim($string);

    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");;

    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\sءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $string);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

    return $string;
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title'         => 'required|max:255',
        'slug'          => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:posts',
        'body'          => 'required',
    ));
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->slug = $this->slug($request->slug);
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('admin/posts')->with('success', 'post is successfully saved');
}
```

It will make slug for each language arabic or english.
and it will work fine.

Comment: Could you please give me the full code and where to add it exactly ?

Comment: I wrote it to you but it's okay i will update the answer

Comment: Have you seen it?

Comment: i got this error

preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 11

Comment: can you send what is the slug have you entered?

Comment: ريال مدريد يتعثر أمام سيلتا فيغو

Comment: Are you still here ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208006/discussion-between-mohammed-aktaa-and-hamad-essa).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's slugging support by transliterating languages such as Arabic is not very good. You could alternatively use PHP's Transliterator https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php to get the transliterated string before sending through Laravel's `Str::slug` function.

For example, you could use something like this:

```
Str::slug(transliterator_transliterate("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; [:Punctuation:] Remove; Lower();", "arabic sentence you need slugged"));
```

Do note that you'd need `PECL intl` installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a correct answer already by @Mohammed Aktaa but it has a missing part of removing backward and forward slashes which can lead to fatal mistake when request the get url that having the slug:

so correct the slug function by the following:

```
public static function slug_ar($string, $separator = '-') {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");
    // '/' and/or '\' if found and not remoeved it will change the get request route
    $string = str_replace('/', $separator, $string); 
    $string = str_replace('\\', $separator, $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\sءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", 
    $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);
    return $string;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This

```
public static function uniqueSlug($slug,$table)
{
    $slug=self::createSlug($slug);

    $items=\DB::table($table)->select('slug')->whereRaw("slug like '$slug%'")->get();

    $count= count($items)+1;

    return $slug.'-'.$count;
}

protected static function createSlug($str)
{
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹يءاأإآؤئبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکكگگلمنوهی]/u", '', $str);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-_]+/", ' ', $string);

    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", '-', $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet of JS to handel the logic in **Laravel 10**

```
        document.getElementById("postTitle").addEventListener("input", function() {
        const postSlug = document.getElementById('postSlug');

        const slugValue = this.value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        postSlug.setAttribute('value', slugValue);
    });
```

It listens to what is written in "post title" field and transforms the spaces into dashes, then send it with the **$request** after validation

Answer (score 0):

For Developers of Larevel, I updated the function of slug() from @mohammed-aktaa

It is enhance Arabic with same functionality as Laravel Str::slug

```
/**
 *  Generates a slug for URL from a given title.
 *
 * @param string $title The title to convert to a slug.
 * @param string $separator The separator to use in the slug. Default is '-'.
 * @param string|null $language The language to use for ASCII conversion. Default is null.
 * @param array $dictionary An array of dictionary words to replace in the slug. Default is ['@' => 'at'].
 * @return string The generated slug.
 */
function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = null, $dictionary = ['@' => 'at']) {
    if (is_null($title)) {
        return "";
    }
    
    if (!is_null($language)) {
        // The peace of code below uses Laravel \Illuminate\Support\Str class
        $title = $language ? \Str::ascii($title, $language) : $title;
    }

    // Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
    $title = trim($title);
    // Make a string lowercase
    $title = mb_strtolower($title, "UTF-8");;

    // Replace dictionary words
    foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value) {
        $dictionary[$key] = $separator.$value.$separator;
    }
    $title = str_replace(array_keys($dictionary), array_values($dictionary), $title);

    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace
    $title = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\sءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $title);
    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace
    $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', mb_strtolower($title));
    // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

    return $title;
}
```